Jakarta 10/11 Migration - Data Source Dependecies
We are in the initial stages of the migration of our web application from Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 11 (Wildfly 26 to Wildfly 34). What is needed for database drivers and data sources? Do the vendor specific database drivers still work or are new versions needed for Jakarta 11 since javax. has been migrated to jakarta.
Thanks

You've tagged both SQL Server and Oracle? Which is it?

We connect to multiple databases; oracle, sql server, postgres.....
the question is the same...do they need new drivers for jakarta 11?

Answer of abovelinked duplicate speaks for itself. Just check the javadocs and listen to the compiler. Hint: JDBC is part of Java SE not Jakarta EE.
